# Simple PHP: mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question about `mysql_num_rows()`,

If I were to have something like this: `mysql_num_rows($getLatest['thread_id'])`
, would it work? Does `mysql_num_rows()` support the use of square brackets, like `['thread_id']` ?

Comment: You could always try it. The best way to learn (at least in my opinion) is to try things and then backtrack to find out why it worked or didn't based on the result. Keeps you sharp, ready to experiment, and learning all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the resource variable with mysql_num_rows..

Suppose you execute a query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
```

SO $result is a resource here. Pass it with  mysql_num_rows(resource)

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Please refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) for further reference.

Comment: and if $getLatest['thread_id'] contains the result, then it'll work. Doesn't matter whether it has square bracket or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

It will work if the array element `$getLatest['thread_id']` contains the result of a `mysql_query()`. I don't see why the square brackets would have something to do with the `mysql_num_rows` call, you're just passing an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function returns the number of rows in a recordset of mysql_query.

Comment: and why would this be an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: because $getLatest['thread_id'] is not related to mysql_num_rows, it will just return the row count